# How to make log4j2 log one file per log call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

Is there a [good practice] way in log4j2 to configure a file appender so it produces one timestamped file per call?

log.error("in file 1");

log.error("in file 2");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be it:

```
<RollingFile name="MyAppender"
          filePattern="/mylogs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss_SSS}.error.log"
          append="false">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n" />
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy />
</RollingFile>
```

`<DirectWriteRolloverStrategy />` is allowing the appender to directly use the filePattern attribute.

`<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />` is allowing the appender to write to a different file each time the pattern is different ( in this case milliseconds `_SSS` )